# How can i directly navigate from cucumber feature file to step definition .TS file?

Tags: typescript, plugins, visual-studio-code, cucumberjs

I am Using VScode with Type script ,But i am unable to find any plugin which directly move my Feature file to the Step Definition file??

Can any one give me the plugin for .ts move directly from .feature cumber file

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you are asking? Are you asking for the ability to click on the step in the feature file and have it bring you to the step definition?

Comment: Yes ,same-Kind of Navigator ,Suppose i have step like "When Login to the URL" on .feature file when i hover mouse pointer to the step so it should provide me one link like hyper link that should navigate to the Step definition of that step (/^Login to the URL$/) .Hope this solved your confusion ?

Comment: Unfortunately there is not built in support for that in VS yet. The closest you can get is this plugin https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexkrechik.cucumberautocomplete which will autocomplete. You could raise that as a feature request in the github repo.

Comment: Thanks :), Suggested the same in Github

Answer (score 0):

Hope someone resolves their issue using this,

in .vsCode/settings.json of your root
add something like this pointing to the step definition file

```
{
    "cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
        "cypress/integration/**/*.ts",
    ],
    "cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinCompletion": true,
}
```

it works on both .ts as well as .js
I've used .ts in the example

more details [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexkrechik.cucumberautocomplete)